# How do I upsert a row that is new or precisely the same as the existing row, and raise an error in every other case?

Tags: sqlite

Suppose we have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);
```

I would like to have an upsert statement that does one of three things:

1. Inserts the row if there is no conflict.
2. Does nothing if the row to be inserted exactly matches the row with which it is in conflict.
3. Raises an error if the row to be inserted does not match the row with which it is in conflict.

For example, I would like something along these lines, where the first statement succeeds and inserts, the second does nothing, and the third fails:

```
INSERT INTO TBL(key, value) VALUES (1, 'foo') ON CONFLICT(key) ...;
INSERT INTO TBL(key, value) VALUES (1, 'foo') ON CONFLICT(key) ...;
INSERT INTO TBL(key, value) VALUES (1, 'bar') ON CONFLICT(key) ...;
```

I don't know what to put in the ellipses, or if this is even the right approach.

Just adding `DO NOTHING` doesn't do what I want, since it won't fail if there is a row mismatch:

```
# Not what I want.
INSERT INTO TBL(key, value) VALUES (1, 'bar') ON CONFLICT(key) DO NOTHING;
```

I can always query after the upsert to see if the row in the table is the same as the one I tried to upsert, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do to this uses a `BEFORE` trigger to do the validation:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE tbl(key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER tbl_validate BEFORE INSERT ON tbl BEGIN
   ...>  SELECT CASE WHEN new.value = tbl.value THEN raise(IGNORE)
   ...>         ELSE raise(ABORT, 'value differs from existing') -- For a better error message
   ...>         END
   ...>  FROM tbl WHERE tbl.key = new.key;
   ...> END;
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(key, value) VALUES (1, 'foo');
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(key, value) VALUES (1, 'foo');
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(key, value) VALUES (1, 'bar');
Error: value differs from existing
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl;
key         value
----------  ----------
1           foo
```